# postgresql rails price range filter with between

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-postgresql, pg

I have the following array of price ranges how can I perform a query to find the price range between these using and operator

This is the array I have

```
["0-1000", "5001_15000", "15001_25000"]
```

Whether this is the only way I have to perform else is ther any methods to perform such filter

```
select * from posts where price between 0 and 1000 and price between 5001 and 15000
```

**Edit-1**

As your said I tried in my console

```
a = [[0,1000],[5001 ,15000], [15001, 25000]]

(a[0].first..a[0].last)
```

This gives `0..1000` and when I try

```
(a[0].first..a[0].last and a[1].first..a[1].last)
```

It shows only `5001..15000` can you explain it please.

**Edit-2**

Only this works how can I add more values

```
Post.where(price: a[0].first..a[0].last)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start adjusting your price range array.
From:

```
["0-1000", "5001_15000", "15001_25000"]
```

to

```
a = [[0,1000],[5001 ,15000], [15001, 25000]]
```

This will give you access to first and last price range bounds with

```
(a[0].first..a[0].last))
```

The above is a range that will product 0..1000 which you can plug into active record, (using the hash syntax of course)

example:

```
Post.where(price: a[0].first..a[0].last)
```

make it into a resusable scope to be able to chain them to accomate the Ands or just write the raw sql.

Hope this helps

Comment: Use scopes as I said.

Comment: sorry am not familiar with scope can you give any sample here

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamic array length, Try this

```
arr = [["0", "100"], ["100", "200"]]
query_string = ""
arr.each {|a| query_string << (arr.last == a ? " price between #{a.first} and #{a.last}"    : "price between #{a.first} and #{a.last} or") }
Product.where(query_string)
```

Which finds the expected records